# Ionic Image is broken after publish and installed the apk

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

i access my images this way and found broken after installing in actual device

```
<ion-avatar item-left>
  <img src="../../assets/uploads/user.jpg">
</ion-avatar>
<h2>{{user?.fullname}}</h2>
<p>{{user?.description}}</p>
<p>{{user?.email}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set incorrect path. Here is how your path must be:

```
<ion-avatar item-left>
  <img src="assets/uploads/user.jpg"> // This is correct path
</ion-avatar>
<h2>{{user?.fullname}}</h2>
<p>{{user?.description}}</p>
<p>{{user?.email}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The path of the image is wrong. Try with:

```
<ion-avatar item-left>
    <img src="assets/uploads/user.jpg">
</ion-avatar>
```